# JAXWS-RI module requires an implementation for each service interface

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, enunciate

I have service and its implemented interface...

My interface has an annotation specifying the service name as name of Service which has implemented that interface .. however the service doesn't have annotation specifying endpoint interface ?

So will this result in failure of wsdl generation ?

I am getting error as :
1> Endpoint interface has no implementations!  It will NOT be deployed...
2> JAXWS-RI module requires an implementation for each service interface

I am using enunciate for web service generation.

my code is like this:

```
// no annotation for endpoint interface
public class ABC implements IABC
{
}

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://ABC", serviceName = "ABC", portName = "ABCPort", name = "ABC")
public interface IABC
{
}
```

Comment: What part of the exception message could not be clearer?

Comment: means when we generate wsdl through enunciate it first looks at implemented service and then at interface or its like it looks with service or interface with annotation and checks if other part has annotation ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate you implementation pointing to the service interface:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="IABC")
public class ABC implements IABC
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I have found it was caused because of a newly thrown checked exception in  my @WebMethod Signature.